# Connect to running libreoffice instance and issue commands from command line

Tags: command-line, libreoffice

Is there a way to connect to a running libreoffice instance (specifically libre office Write) to issue commands?

As an example of what I'm interested in, you can connnect to an open MS Word instances via COM using any command-line tool with COM support - powershell or your favourite scripting language and issue some rudimentary editting commands.

Is there any such equivalent?

or even a more limited equivalent such as mozilla/firefox `--remote` options?

The classes of commands I'd be interested in would be simple file operations, save with new name, close, open,... but anything could be useful.

Comment: There are different tools by Bernard Marcelly to access OpenOffice / LO using COM: http://bernard.marcelly.perso.sfr.fr/index2.html. For running LO as server and connect using C++, see the LO 4.5 SDK examples: http://api.libreoffice.org/examples/examples.html